# Eliminate the need for SQL Server tools installation

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a VS 2012 C# application (that I've inherited) that, in order to properly operate, you first need to install

- SQL Server Data Tools
- Client Tool Connectivity
- Management Tools

Without those prerequisites, the application does not work.

I have the following referenced in the application:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
- Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum

In basic the application allows for SQL statements to be run against a database and it allows a user to run a backup of a selected database to disk (on the server)

At various points, the application will list all the databases using `GetSchema`, it will execute SQL using `ExecuteNonQuery` and it will backup the database with `SqlBackup(server)`

I've tried removing some of the above references but doing so ends up in build errors so my assumption is that I need them all.  I've tried to run the application without installing the 3 SQL Server items above with no luck.

Is it possible for me to eliminate the installation requirements of SQL Server Data Tools, Client Tool Connectivity and Management Tools somehow? Can I include all of these in my project so the end user does not have to install anything additional?

Obviously I'm new to this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I typically handle a situation like this since there aren't any NuGet packages to support this that I've found yet.

1. Create a folder in your project called "References" (can also be Libraries or something else)
2. Track down the DLLs that you need for the import statements above and copy them to your References folder.
3. In Visual Studio, remove all references to the libraries above in the "References" section in your project file.
4. Right click on the References section in your project and select "Add Reference..."
5. Select the "Browse" option on the left and navigate to your Reference folder and all of your DLLs.
6. Click "OK" and rebuild. This should copy the DLLs into the bin folder for deployment / use.

The main reason you keep a separate folder for your references instead of copying them into the bin folder is that if the solution is cleaned, or a lot of times during compilation, the bin folder is flushed out. If you only have them there you lose them. You also typically don't commit the bin folder into source control, but you want to make sure these particular DLLs are referenced for source control and compiling.

Answer (score 4):

Just bin-deploy those assemblies. Reference them from their on-disk paths (for me: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll"`) instead of from the GAC. You'll have to replace the existing assembly references with new ones.

Comment: As a side note to this, make sure the license allows for redistribution of the DLLs.

Comment: I don't think you are licensed to distribute those files with your program. [The MSDN says](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff713979(v=sql.105).aspx)  you need to use [the redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True#smo)

Comment: Thanks, I went with @Dillie-O's answer only because of the details included (looks like you were both explaining the same thing.  Looks like I can't do what I want due to licensing anyway...